# Multi tab user registration form angular 8

Tags: html, forms, angular8, registration, ng-bootstrap

I am using angular 8 and ng-bootstrap for my development. I want to have a user registration form with multiple tabs. How can I achieve this without changing my url pattern or you can say while hovering between tabs it should not route to another url or so. This is something I want to achieve with previous and next buttons and submit button at last tab. Please help. For reference click on the image provided. Thanks in advance
[reference form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPvIa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems pretty straightforward, if I have interpreted your question correctly.

1. Use [Nav](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview) instead of [Tabset](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples) since ng-bootstrap have deprecated tabset above 6.0 version.
2. Use the **activeId** inputs exposed in [NgbNav Api](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/api) to change the current active tab on click of *Next* or *Previous* Buttons. I have used a variable `active` to keep track of it.
3. Add some corner case logic in ts file to not overshoot or undercut the range. (depends on the number of segments in your form)
4. Change the last label of the last *Next* button based on `active`.

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iel3cl)

Comment: thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Kindly mark this an accepted answer if it served your purpose, will help my reputation.